# Does separation the project into libraries reduce compilation time?

Tags: java, spring

I have a big Spring web project. It contains lots of files and functionality. It takes a lot of time for it to build and start (I use mvn to compile and tomcat to run the application). I think it is impossible to reduce the startup time of the project without removing functionality, but what about the compilation time? What if I separate the project into multiple libraries (like library to work with DB, another one that contains some services), compile them separately? The compilation time of the main part of the project will decrease???

Comment: Well managed dependencies, even within your project, are able to do that, yes. But without knowing details, there's no meaningful answer of more than yes/no/it depends.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes. I have worked on largish JSP/Tomcat projects, and the turnaround time for a JSP change, compile and deploy was under 30 seconds. Of course this will not apply if you need to modify a library. Then the time will be longer.

We did find that the libraries should be small and focused. Llibraries that required other libraries extended fix times greatly.